# How to get data-value in the html div?

Tags: javascript, html

I can get all entries' attribute like style display in the div. but I can't get the data-value from the same way. I need find a correct syntax to get the all data-value entries.

```js
  $.ajax({
      url:"{{ url_for('fetch_bar') }}",
      type:"post",
      dataType: "json",
      async: true,
      success:function(response){
        var response = JSON.parse(response);
        var len = Object.keys(response).length;

        var selects = document.querySelectorAll("select[id=select_host]");
        var bars = document.querySelectorAll("[id=ldBar]");
        if (len == 1) {
           ....
        }
        else if (len > 1)
          for( var ind = 0; ind < len; ind++){
            for (var index = 0; index < selects.length ; index++)
              if (selects[index].value == response[ind].hostname)
                // alert(bars[index].style.display)
                alert(bars[index].data-value)
                // alert(bars[index].[data-value])
```

```html
                  <td>

                        <input id="stage" type="button" class="btn-primary" onclick="readTextFile();"  name="stage" value="{{entry.stage}}" >
                        <div id="ldBar" class="ldBar label-center" data-value="0" data-preset="stripe" data-aspect-ratio="none" style="width:100%;display: block;" ></div>
                  </td>
                  <td>
```

Comment: Try the following snippet `document.getElementById("ldBar").dataset["value"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.getAttribute("data-value")` to get the value

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('#ldBar').getAttribute("data-value"))
```

```html
 <div id="ldBar" class="ldBar label-center" data-value="0" data-preset="stripe" data-aspect-ratio="none" style="width:100%;display: block;" ></div>
```

Comment: that's awesome! thank you for your prompt reply on this. yes it works and I can now set the attribute as well ! thanks again Ellipsis !

Comment: Hi Ellipsis, for the attribute set I've done for data-value, the web page won't load new value automatic but I have to refresh the page, is it mean I have to reload the page periodically ? any other good method ? I know it's another topic .. - -b

Comment: No. You don't need to refresh the page to show the changed value. Change the value inside a function and it will reflect in place

Comment: I use this to change the attribute successfully, but the value didn't reflect on page until I refresh it. strange...
bars[index].setAttribute("data-value",response[ind].status);

Comment: @ellipsis you sir, are a legend! Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get `data-value` of the element with jQuery:

```js
console.log($("div").data("value"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-value=10><div>
```

Vanilla JS:

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('div').getAttribute("data-value"));
```

```html
<div data-value=10></div>
```

Dataset:

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('div').dataset.value);
```

```html
<div data-value=10><div>
```

Comment: Thank you shrys for help taking look !

Answer (score 1):

If you have event then you can simply use it by:

```
const { dataset: { value }} = e.target;
```

or you can directly get it by using JQuery:

```
$("#your_element_id").data("value")
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the `data` attribute from an element using jQuery use this syntax:

`$("#your_element_id").data("value")`

Just note that if you write it like this in your html:
`<div id='test' data-testID='1'></div>`

In jQuery you will access it like this:

`$("#test").data("testid");`

As all the data properties are returned as lowercase

Comment: Thank you Igor for taking look at this, I've found my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use`dataset`, like this:

```js
const ldBar = document.getElementById("ldBar")
console.log(
  ldBar.dataset.value,
  ldBar.dataset.preset,
  ldBar.dataset.aspectRatio // Note the conversion to camelCase
);
```

```html
<div 
  id="ldBar"
  class="ldBar label-center"
  data-value="0"
  data-preset="stripe"
  data-aspect-ratio="none"
  style="width:100%; display: block;" 
></div>
```

(See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)

Comment: Thank you Cat for your comment , I've got my answer.

Comment: thank you Cat, I've tried and your answer is correct ! only that I still have to refresh my page to reflect the new value... don't know why..

Answer (score 0):

HTML CODE:

```
<td>
    <input id="stage" type="button" class="btn-primary" onclick="readTextFile();"  name="stage" value="{{entry.stage}}" >
    <div id="ldBar" class="ldBar label-center" data-value="0" data-preset="stripe" data-aspect-ratio="none" style="width:100%;display: block;" ></div>
</td>
```

JS CODE:

```
var abc = $('td').find('#ldBar').attr('data-value');
```